# Maintain model class instance on server between 2 seperate users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a two player board game. Using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3, postgres 8.4.

I was wondering if it is possible to create model class (Called "Game") that will maintain the state of the game as the 2 players make ajax calls to it? (Current pieces locations on board, current move, ect).

In other words, can I do this so as to avoid creating a database table that must load the game state on each player turn?

If its possible, any quick example would be appreciated very much :)

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for not creating a database table? Are you asking for some NoSQL solution? I guess you want to have simple Ruby object store available to all Rails app server instances, correct?

Comment: No major reason for it, was just curious if it was possible to do it without a DB table. Suppose I was just thinking I could cut down on number of database updates if I could do it another way. Yes, in answer to you rails app server instances question. I can use a DB table, really I haven't got a whole lot of time so the quickest solution is probably the best. Would that be the database table option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use database(or any third party storage) because if you would be able to share session id between two users somehow then it will be security hole.

I would suggest mamcache storage if you want better performance.

Comment: I'm going to go with a DB solution for now. I might look at adding that memcache functionality in future, looks interesting. Thanks Greg.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly, but what if to use CanCan gem for that? Can sound strange, but maybe two roles like "player 1" and "player 2" will work)

Comment: In this case, database will be involved.

Comment: I'll take a quick look at that Kishie. I'm looking for the fastest solution. Doesn't matter if its DB or not.